# Mercurial distributed repositories

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, teamcity

Having myself found in a role of a build engineer and a systems guy I had to learn end figure out a few things - namely how to set up our infrastructure. Before I came on board they didn't have any. With this in mind please excuse me if I ask anything that should have been obvious.

We currently have 3 level distributed mercurial repositories: level one on each of developer machines, level two on central (trunk) server - only accessible from local network and the third layer on BitBucket. Workflow is as follows:

1. Local development: developer pulls change-sets from local network server. developer commits to local and pushes to our local server once merge conflicts are resolved. A scheduled script overnight backs everything up to BitBucket.
2. Working from home: developer pulls change-sets from BitBucket. Developer comits to their local repo and push to BitBucket.
3. TeamCity picks up repo changes from local network server for each project and runs a build / automated deploy to test environment.

The issue I'm hitting is scenario 2: at the moment if someone pushes something to bitbucket it's their responsibility to merge it back when they're back in office. And it's a bit of a time waster if it could be automated.

In case you're wondering, the reason we have a central repo on local network is because it would be slow to run TeamCity builds of BitBucket repositories. Haven't tested so it's just an educated guess.

Anyhow, the script that is scheduled and pushes all changes from central repository on local network just runs a "hg push" for each of repositories. It would have to do a pull / merge beforehand. How do I do this right?

This is what the pull would have to use switches for:
- update after pull
- in case of merge conflicts, always take newer file
- in case of error, send an email to system administrator(s)
- anything extra?

Please feel free to share your own setup as long as it's not vastly different to what's described.

UPDATE: In light of recent answers I feel an important aspect if the intended approach needs to be clarified. The idea is not to force merges on our local network central repo. Instead it should resolve merge conflicts in same was as per using HgWorkbench on developer machines with post pull: update + merge. All developers have this on by default so it should be OK.

So the script / batch file on server would do the following:

1. pull from BitBucket
2. update + auto merge
3. Any merge auto conflicts?

   3.1 Yes -> Send an email to administrators to manually merge -> Break

   3.2 No -> Cary on
4. Get outgoing changesets. Will push create multiple heads? (This might be redundant because of pull / update)

   4.1 Yes -> Prompt administrators. Break.

   4.2 No -> Push changes

Hope this clears things up a bit. Now, can this be done using hg commands alone - batch -  or do I have to script it? Specifically can it send emails?

Thanks.

Comment: Changing TeamCity to run from BitBucket should be trivial. And since you're just guessing that it would be slower, I think you should try it before you try to solve this problem.  It's strange to have essentially two copies of the same layer (both BitBucket and the local central server)

Comment: Admittedly it might be strange to have two layers. But this is what distributed means to me. It should be able to handle any number of layers. Anyway, I'll try hooking up the build to BitBucket directly and see how it goes. It's not as trivial as you might think because you have to start playing with optimizations - reduce amount of source code downloaded for each build (not clean certain folders), possibly even restructure some solutions to meet this demand. Golden rule: each plan takes three times as long to execute as planned :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So all your work is available at BitBucket, right? Why not make BitBucket (as available from anywhere) you primary repo source and dropping your local servers? You can pull changes from BitBucket with TeamCity for your nightly builds and developers whould always work with current repo at BitBucket and resolve all merging problems themselves so there wouldn't be any subsequent merges for you.

Comment: Thanks kworr. To be honest we were contemplating doing this. However Mercurial is supposed to be a distributed source control system. The reasons we've kept a local central server is first: performance and second is our CTO is still a bit paranoid about not having a central local copy of all the code. Guess we could reverse the roles with ButBucket though. Will consider.

Comment: Well Mercurial is a DVCS by desing but noone will force you to use all of its design possibilities.

Comment: You can always setup your local server to pull changes from BitBucket to have another backup of you repo. I'm not a Mercurial guru but you also can pull changes from local server and push them to BitBucket. And you can also reject pushes on local server to force any push to BitBucket.

Comment: Guess I'll hook it up to BitBucket as you suggested. Looks like there won't be enough time to test out any other setup. Thanks for sanity check :)

Comment: Just in case someone comes across this - we've hooked up BitBucket as primary repositories a while ago. Seems to be working fine. The only downside so far was on two occasions when office internet went down and the Build server couldn't access the repositories. Build process hasn't really taken any massive impact in terms of build times.

Answer (score 2):

I would not try to automatically merge the changes if they are conflicting, this will only lead to broken and inconsistent versions and "lost" changes causing confusion and chaos. Don't merge it automatically if it isn't clear how that merge should look like.

A better alternative would be to just keep the two heads around and push/pull them without merging. This way everybody still can get that version of the data he was working on from work/home. A manual merge will have to be done, but this can also be done at work or from home, enabling developers to resolve the issue from wherever they are. You can also send emails around in this scenario to make sure everybody is aware of the problem.

Comment: Thanks sth. You've raised a few good issues with intended approach. I'll add an UPDATE to main question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you could automize this using a script, I would try PowerShell if I were you. However, sometimes this may require manual change merges when there are conflicts (because when developers commit changes to both BB and local repos, these changes might be conflicting).

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion Marek. Makes sense however I'd like to explore hg commands that are packed up in a batch file. This will certainly be a fallback option if other possibilities fail. Good point about manual merges.